# Why there is three root user in mariaDB database server?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select host,user from mysql.user where user='root';
+-----------+------+
| host      | user |
+-----------+------+
| 127.0.0.1 | root |
| ::1       | root |
| localhost | root |
+-----------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What is the significance of each and what is the difference between these?
Is this scenario common for all system?

Comment: In MySQL/MariaDB, those are three different users. (A user is identified by a username and a hostname.) Each of those individual users can have different sets of privileges. We aren't limited to three,  we could have more than three users with user=root, each with a different hostname.

Answer (score 2):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-names.html says:

> A host value can be a host name or an IP address (IPv4 or IPv6). The name 'localhost' indicates the local host. The IP address '127.0.0.1' indicates the IPv4 loopback interface. The IP address '::1' indicates the IPv6 loopback interface.

MySQL treats 'localhost' different from '127.0.0.1' which confuses some people who are accustomed to those two being the same. In MySQL, if a client connects to host 'localhost', it uses the UNIX socket, which is a little bit faster than using a TCP/IP connection. Or at least it was once upon a time.